# Having Trouble with mod_rewrite on hosting server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently did a complete site overhaul. The site had way more content than users cared about so we decided to really scale back. I am trying to set up a few rewrite rules to catch old site locations and funnel them to the correct place on the new site, just to avoid some unnecessary 404 hits.

Everything is going great except for one line. The whole thing works great on my localhost, but when I move it to dev or prod one line doesn't work.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^events/(.*)" "/#concert-section" [R,L,NE]
RewriteRule "^(.*)/purchase-brents-recordings" "/#purchase-section" [R,L,NE]
RewriteRule "^Bio\.html$" "/#about-section" [R,L,NE]
RewriteRule "^m$" "/" [R,L,NE]
RewriteRule "^(.*)/contact-brent" "/#contact-section" [R,L,NE]
```

Everything works except for the 'events' line. I tried this as well:

```
RewriteRule "^events/(.*)$" "/#concert-section" [R,L,NE]
```

Both work just fine on my localhost, but both are ignored on dev and prod which are on the same hosting server. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the fix for this. Apparently it is a common goddady problem and the answer was to add the following to my .htaccess file above my rewrites:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

I am still unclear as to why this fixes the problem (I'm more of a front-end person) and why this only was a problem for the one rule. So if you stumble on this and know why, please feel free to comment on my answer.